# How to remove line from System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba, removeclass, my.settings

I want to remove a line or a text from my application settings .
example: My.Settings.Bookmarks.
here is information in my settings of Bookmarks:
Name: Bookmarks | Type: System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection | Scope: User.
Can anyone help me please because it's important

Comment: The Remove() or RemoveAt() method jumps to mind.  Have you tried?

Comment: Yes I tried Remove() but doesn't works but RemoveAt() helped me

Answer (score 2):

Here from MSDN

[StringCollection.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[StringCollection.RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.removeat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The first one requires the string to remove, the second one the index of the string in the collection.

Suppose to have

```
StringCollection sCol = new StringCollection();
sCol.Add("STEVE");
sCol.Add("JOHN");
sCol.Remove("STEVE");
```

Really simple

Comment: Thnx, this is helpful I tried ....Remove but it doesn't work but ....RemoveAt it's help me Thnx

Comment: RemoveAt is better if you know the position, Remove if you know exctly the string to remove.